# FFMPEG: how to select audio stream without language metadata

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, globalization

I have some source Video files with one or more audio streams inside.
I would to encode each source file with Italian language. Then I can do it.

```
ffmpeg -i source-file.avi -c:v ... -c:a ... -map 0:a:m:language:ita ...
```

But some source file has audio stream without Language metadata.
I look that it is possible to set Language metadata with "und" special value. Then I try to select the audio stream with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i source-file.avi -c:v ... -c:a ... -map 0:a:m:language:ita? -map 0:a:m:language:und? ...
```

(the "?" char say to ffmpeg that he do not fire exception if the audio stream do not exists).
Unfortunatelly this command do not works... It seems that ffmpeg search the "und" language instead of search a audio stream "without" language.

## Video MetaData

This is the video MetaData where audio stream do not have language value:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'D:\My-Video.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : My-Video
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.3 + libmatroska v1.4.4
    creation_time   : 2016-01-20T16:02:03.000000Z
  Duration: 01:15:28.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2775 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 2387529
      BPS-eng         : 2387529
      DURATION        : 01:15:28.920000000
      DURATION-eng    : 01:15:28.920000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 113223
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 113223
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 1351616420
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1351616420
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.7.0 ('All of the above') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.7.0 ('All of the above') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-01-20 16:02:03
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-01-20 16:02:03
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 384000
      BPS-eng         : 384000
      DURATION        : 01:15:28.928000000
      DURATION-eng    : 01:15:28.928000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 141529
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 141529
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 217388544
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 217388544
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.7.0 ('All of the above') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.7.0 ('All of the above') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-01-20 16:02:03
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-01-20 16:02:03
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2(ita): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 720x576 (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 2218
      BPS-eng         : 2218
      DURATION        : 01:09:57.232000000
      DURATION-eng    : 01:09:57.232000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 965
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 965
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 1163769
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1163769
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.7.0 ('All of the above') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.7.0 ('All of the above') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-01-20 16:02:03
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-01-20 16:02:03
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan: Full log added